# Winsock - Select's timeout on Listening socket causing every subsequent Select call to fail

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, network-programming, winsock

I would like to preface this by saying my problem is solved completely by removing the timeout option of Select() by setting it to NULL.

But i want to use a timeout, so here is my problem. The server program is very simply&plain, it listens for connections, accepts them and prints to the console.

The problem is that after the first timeout on select, select will return -1 (MSDN gives me little-to-no documentation as to what would cause -1 to be returned from select(), only that it an error signal) and effectively stop any more communication from the program.

**Server - main.cpp**

```
int main(){

    /* variables */
    int iResult, iSendResult;
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    bool exit=false;
    int foundRoom, tempFoundRoom;
    fd_set readfds, writefds;
    struct timeval tv;
    long double counter=0;
    int maxfd=0;

    /* Server variables */
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    SOCKET ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
    struct addrinfo hints;


    printf("~SERVER~\n");

     /* Initialize Winsock*/
    initialize_winsock(wsaData, hints, &result);

    /* Set socket and bind to TCP listening socket */
    set_socketandbind(ListenSocket, result, maxfd);

    //non-blocking mode
    u_long iMode=1;
    ioctlsocket(ListenSocket,FIONBIO,&iMode);
    ioctlsocket(ClientSocket,FIONBIO,&iMode);

    // clear the set ahead of time
    FD_ZERO(&readfds);
    //FD_ZERO(&writefds);

    //add our descriptors to the set
    FD_SET(ListenSocket, &readfds);

    //wait until either socket has data ready to be recv()d (timeout 5 secs)
    tv.tv_sec = 5;
    tv.tv_usec = 0;

    /* main loop */
    for(;;){
        cout << "Maxfd: " << ListenSocket << " \ " << maxfd << endl;

        //select
        int rv = select(ListenSocket+1, &readfds, NULL, NULL, &tv);

        cout << "Updateing... rv: " << rv << endl;

        if (rv == -1) {
            perror("Select: "); // error occurred in select()
        }else if (rv == 0){
            printf("Timeout occurred! No data after 5 seconds.\n");
        }else{

            // one or both of the descriptors have data
            if (FD_ISSET(ListenSocket, &readfds)) {

                // Accept a client socket
                ClientSocket=accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);

                cout << "Connected a user." << endl;

            }

            counter++;
        }

        cout << endl;
        Sleep(500);

    };

    /* Unset server socket */
    closesocket(ListenSocket);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The output should be, timeout, timeout, timeout, because thats how select() is supposed to work, and how it works on my client. Instead the output is timeout, error, error, error:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to reset 'TV' and the FD structures every time around the loop.

Comment: You mean every time select() is called it resets the tv structure?

Comment: This actually doesnt solve the problem. I needed add FD_ZERO and FD_SET and reset tv in the loop, not only add the tv every loop. Why is this?

Comment: Because select() changes the FD structures. If you got a timeout,  nothing was ready, so the corresponding bit got cleared, so you needed to reset it.

Comment: I was actually mistaken, but now i pretty sure i know 100% of the problem and the solution. When select() is timeout'd for a particular socket, the socket in that fd(ie: readfds) is deleted, so when it timed out it deleted the only socket in the fd. Since there is no more sockets in the fd, it had no choice but to return error because theres no sockets to check. The solution was the FD_SET that  socket in the fd(ie: readfds) again every time it timeout's that socket for readability for example. Works perfect now, thank you!

Comment: That's exactly what I just said.